# Detox test failed on typeText if text is "long"

Tags: react-native, mocha.js, detox

Have some interesting problem with detox testing!

All configs are clearly right (cause in another case it wasn't even work, yeah?)
Work with Mocha tests, and yes, it works.
I use redux to work with state and custom components in my main component.

```
<OpacityInput
   idTest="LoginEmailInput"
   icon="account"
   placeholder="Login..."
   value={this.props.email}
   onChangeText={this.emailChanged}
 />
```

So i pass all data by props to component (testID and value for inputs i pass too)...and here is my test (i make two restricted test to catch an error)

```
 it('should find input login', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('LoginEmailInput'))).toBeVisible()
  })

  it('should type text login', async () => {
    await element(by.id('LoginEmailInput')).typeText('test@test.com')
  })
```

And it is really interesting...if i want to type 'a'(two-three symbol max) - it is ok! Text passing with no problem! But when i change my 'a' to real e-mail...it crash!

I have a strange feeling that detox has only few seconds for typeText, and if it can't so...it crash :)

Here is the error after crash. I used

> detox test —loglevel trace

for details. Test on IOS 6[image: first][image: second][image: third]

Comment: Detox@8.2.2 is a faulty version. Please update and see if it solves your issue

Comment: @Rotemmiz i have a 8.2.1 version and dunno why can't upgrade

Comment: we solved this crash in 8.2.3